# Storing user info to session or load them directly from sql when request is made?

Tags: php, mysql

Another, maybe dummie, question. I'm making a website and now I've dilemma between `$_SESSION` and requesting user data directly from the table itself. So, my two ideas right now:

1. Retrieve needed values from mySQL and then set them to `$_SESSION` array. So, when I need something I can just call `$_SESSION["username"]`. It has some disadvantages also. For example, if admin changes some user data, ie username(that is a lame example, but still).
2. Retrieve value straight from SQL. In this case I can call some function what calls a SQL query and gives me result.

So, question is, which method is better to use or there are any alternatives you can suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to add some things to my post. In first case, the user wont be able to see change till next login.

Comment: Store commonly used data in the `$_SESSION` then if things change, make sure you change the value in the `$_SESSION` at change time. Otherwise, you'll have a ton of queries going on.

Comment: use a session unless you are thinking that some of those values will change.

Comment: Yes, but there is no way that I can handle other user $_SESSION or there is?

Comment: then do not hold username in SESSION, instead hold user id, and don't let the admin to change the user id. once an account created, it's user id shouldn't be modified.

Comment: In most applications that I've worked on we make the compromise that the the data in the session is valid for the duration of the session. If things change, the user will get the changes on the next login.

Comment: it's really just a judgement call, if you feel the data is static then use a session, otherwise don't

Comment: Thanks everybody to give me advice on that.

Answer (score 3):

For frequently-used data but relatively unchanging data, such as names ("Hello, $firstname, welcome back") that would be used on every page request, you probably should cache them in the session. The slight additional parsing/loading overhead will be far less than having to yank that data out of the DB each time.

For relatively critical data, e.g. 'account is disabled', you may want to hit the database each time. However, this would depend on your security needs. If it's ok for a banned user to be able to wander around your system for a short period after their account is disabled, you can implement a time-out counter in the session, e.g. after every 50 hits, you refresh the data in the session regardless.

Comment: Hm, thanks for the tip you said with last sentence. I'm gonna definetly use something like that.

Comment: you could also possibly rummage around the session save directory (available via `session_save_path()`) to find a particular user's session file(s) and load/update them externally anytime the user's data is modified by an admin. but that'd be rather painful.

Answer (score 1):

do not hold username in SESSION, instead hold user id, and don't let the admin to change the user id. once an account created, it's user id shouldn't be modified. and for each page load check stuff from DB.